# nginx redirect to multi docker container

Tags: docker, nginx

I need to configure a redirect to two different containers through the server.
My docker-compose file:

```
web_app:
  image: ${WEB_APP_IMAGE}
  ports:
    - ${WEB_APP_PORT}:80

dashboard:
  image: ${DASHBOARD_IMAGE}
  ports:
    - ${DASHBOARD_PORT}:80
```

nginx.conf:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://web_app;
    proxy_redirect off;
}

location /admin {
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://dashboard;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

The web app is working correctly, but the "location /admin" doesn't redirect me to the dashboard container. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is docker-agnostic. Since you are using docker-compose to spin up your containers, you need to provide the IP:PORT to the proxy_pass directive.

Also, you might want to switch the location directives between each other.

Try this:

```
location /admin {
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:${DASHBOARD_PORT};
    proxy_redirect off;
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:${WEB_APP_PORT};
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Comment: I think this is not a proxy_pass problem, because when I write `proxy_pass http://dashboard;` from `location /`, I see my admin panel, but I tried and got no changes.
Moving the admin directive to the top did not help me too.

Comment: Does the container with nginx have to have visibility on the target they are passing the traffic to? In my setup, I have nginx and I'm getting traffic into it but the proxy pass statements do not work.